# External Sort giving OutOfMemory in a readInt() call

Tags: java, sorting, merge, external

I'm using External Sort with merging to sort files of integers. Typically a solution to this would be to increase the heapsize of the JVM using -Xmx, but I was wondering if there exists a way to better my code without increasing the heapsize.

The method that threw the error is the merge method.

```
public static void merge(RandomAccessFile a1, RandomAccessFile a2, RandomAccessFile b1,DataOutputStream output, int start, int end) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    //a1: file being read from
    //b1: file being written to

    if((int)a1.length() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    DataInputStream input_a1 = new DataInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(a1.getFD())));

    DataInputStream input_a2 = new DataInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(a2.getFD())));


    b1.seek(start); //set output pointer to start


    int mid = (start + end) /2;
    int file_length = (int)a1.length();


    //basically if second block is empty so just copy
    if (end > file_length) {
        end = file_length;
        if (end <= mid) {
            //copy from start to EOF

            int no_of_ints_left = (file_length - start)/4;
            for(int i = 1; i <= no_of_ints_left; i++) {

                output.writeInt(input_a1.readInt());
            }
            output.flush();

            return;
        }
    }


    int first_counter = start;
    int second_counter = mid;

    int x;
    int y;

    while(first_counter < mid && second_counter < end) {
        input_a1.mark(first_counter);
        input_a2.mark(second_counter);
        x = input_a1.readInt();
        y = input_a2.readInt();
        if(x < y) {
            output.writeInt(x);
            input_a2.reset();
            first_counter += 4;
        }
        else {
            output.writeInt(y);
            input_a1.reset();
            second_counter += 4;
        }
    }
    output.flush();
    if(first_counter == mid) {
        int no_of_ints_left = (end - second_counter)/4;

        while(no_of_ints_left > 0){
            x = input_a2.readInt();
            output.writeInt(x);
            no_of_ints_left--;
        }

    }
    else {
        int no_of_ints_left = (mid - first_counter)/4;
        while(no_of_ints_left > 0){
            x  = input_a1.readInt();
            output.writeInt(x);
            no_of_ints_left--;
        }
    }
    output.flush();
    input_a1 = null;
    input_a2 = null;
    return;

}
```

The line that caused the OutOfMemory error is the x = input_a1.readInt() line, but I doubt this is the reason for the error. I tried calling System.gc() after each call to merge(), but that did not fix the problem. What other ways could I optimise the method such that it uses less memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code use `mark` on a buffered stream. That will require the entire marked section to be in memory, which is probably your problem.

`RandomAccessFile` is probably the easiest way to get the same functionality but keeping the data on disk. Memory mapping with `java.nio` is a more complex technique - and can still run into problems on 32-bit machines. However, I guess you are still likely to run into severe performance problems for large files.

(Also a stack trace is useful to see exactly what allocation failed. Probably reallocating a buffer. Although profiling the heap will tell you what's actually taking up memory.)